# Deleting old Docs from particular index using curator plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-curator

I have installed curator plugin for deleting docs of particular index. So

1. Can curator plugin can be used to delete a  Doc's of a index/indices OR it is only used to delete the entire indices. If possible can you share any sample.
2. To delete a indices also is it mandatory to have alias created for that indices.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. Curator cannot be used to delete documents from an index.  It can only be used to manage (delete, alias, allocate, open, close, etc.) [entire indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about.html).

Answer 2. No alias is necessary for deleting indices.  In fact, to delete an index, you must refer to it by name (or wildcard, if allowed).  Deleting an alias will not result in deletion of the associated index.